# what makes two networks different?

Tags: networking, router

When can we say two networks are different from each other? Is it when they have different subnet masks or when they use different policies? Will it be right to say that a router is needed to connect two 'different' networks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

client 1 : 192.168.0.10
client 2 : 192.168.1.10

are those clients in the same network ?

this depends on the netmask they are using.

If they are set to use :

255.255.255.0 : then they are not on the same network
255.255.0.0   : then they are on the same network

It is however right to say "a router is needed to connect 2 different networks" , this would then be called "routing"

see the following :

A /24 network may be divided into the following subnets by increasing the subnet mask successively by one bit. This affects the total number of hosts that can be addressed in the /24 network (last column).

Prefix size     Network mask    Available
subnets     Usable hosts
per subnet  Total
usable hosts

/24     255.255.255.0   1   254     254
/25     255.255.255.128     2   126     252
/26     255.255.255.192     4   62  248
/27     255.255.255.224     8   30  240
/28     255.255.255.240     16  14  224

/29     255.255.255.248     32  6   192
/30     255.255.255.252     64  2   128
/31     255.255.255.254     128     2 256

table can be found on :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. That's what a router is by definition. You can make your own study on what the difference between a router and a switch is.

As for the first part of your question, basically, networks are different if they do not connect directly. So two subnets of one net may be considered different and separate, as they will need a router to bridge them.